# Best Drupal module for mailing lists?

Tags: 7, emails, organic-groups

I am working on a Drupal based site for a church and one of the items is a method for each group to have discussions.

I immediately thought OG would be a good fit but after consideration I'm not sure it will be enough by itself.

The goals are:

1.)  Users will be able to join a group or groups.

2.)  Each group will have private content for members only.

3.)  Each group will also have a mailing list for 2-way communication (so I don't believe SimpleNews will work).  Ideally, when a user is approved to join a group they will also be subscribed to that groups mailing list.

OG will be a good fit for the first 2 items.

I'm not sure about the third.

I've used Mailman in the past but it appears the mailman modules for Drupal are limited to Drupal 6.

What is the best way to achieve this in Drupal 7?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Message module along with the message notify module. Message module is Drupal 7's answer to activity-streams and a flexible Messaging & Notifications system.

http://drupal.org/project/message
http://drupal.org/project/message_notify

Comment: Does the message module allow 2 way email communication?

Comment: 2 way email communication between users or user and groups?

Answer (score 1):

I have used http://drupal.org/project/og_mailinglist quite successfully on a Drupal 6 site, but I have not checked the progress on the 7.x-1.x-dev branch that is in progress.  It looks like some people are using it; see: http://drupal.org/node/1920282

Comment: I'm using OG Mailinglist on Drupal 7 with good results